# Laravel deploying 403 Access Forbideen

Tags: laravel, deploying

I'm trying to deploy my laravel 8 project in my hosting. 
After I publich whole files of the projct, I got the 403 Access Forbidden. 
My websites on the server work perfectly, but this project I don't know what's is the problem. 
And I'm sure that the problem in the project files not in the server. 
This is the website: [Sheeks] (http://manage-sheek.manarat-free.com/)

Comment: This is a very broad question statement. You should try to check for already available answers related to how to host Laravel app on apache or nginx whatever your webserver is. Then try to figure out what  would have gone wrong and attempt to fix. If still you can't get it working come back and post what did you attempt to do and seek further suggestions. Mostly it can be related to `vhost` config or permissions for `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folders in the app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your configurations at server is correct then it's because of cached data. Run commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```